# Why is this scss code to select a random color from a list raising an error?

Tags: python, flask, sass, flask-assets

I am creating a web application using flask and am using flask_assets and pyscss to compile my scss. I am trying to give each section in the HTML a random color from a list using scss and this is what I have so far. The following scss code generates a *500 Internal Server Error*. I know the scss compiles correctly as the error is generated only when this code is added to the file. The file already has an `@import` which works fine. Why is this error generated? Does it have something to do with pyscss? I've been debating accomplishing this using JavaScript if it cannot be done using scss.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_assets import Environment, Bundle

app = Flask(__name__)
assets = Environment(app)

def generate_scss_bundles() -> dict:
    scss_dir = 'static/scss'
    return {
        f'{filename}_style': Bundle(
            f'scss/{filename}.scss',
            filters='pyscss',
            depends='**/*.scss',
            output=f'gen/{filename}.css'
        )
        for filename in [os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir(scss_dir) if f[0] != '_']
    }

assets.register(generate_scss_bundles())
```

**SCSS**

```
@use 'sass:math';

$colors: $color1-purple, $color1-pink, $color1-orange, $color1-yellow, $color1-green, $color1-blue;

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
    section:nth-child(#{length($colors)}n+#{$i}) {
        background-color: nth($colors, math.random(length($colors)));
    }
}
```

**Error message**

> scss.errors.SassSyntaxError: Syntax error after 'nth($colors, math':
> Found '.random(le' but expected one of ",", ":", ADD, ALPHA_FUNCTION,
> AND, BANG_IMPORTANT, BAREWORD, COLOR, DIV, DOUBLE_QUOTE, END, EQ,
> FNCT, GE, GT, IF_FUNCTION, INTERP_END, INTERP_START, LE,
> LITERAL_FUNCTION, LPAR, LT, MOD, MUL, NE, NOT, NUM, OR, RPAR, SIGN,
> SINGLE_QUOTE, SPACE, SUB, URL_FUNCTION, VAR

I tried removing the math module as suggessted in the error message but this raises a new error.

**SCSS**

```
$colors: $color1-purple, $color1-pink, $color1-orange, $color1-yellow, $color1-green, $color1-blue;

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
    section:nth-child(#{length($colors)}n+#{$i}) {
        background-color: nth($colors, random(length($colors)));
    }
}
```

**Error message**

> ValueError: Invalid index <String 'random(6)'>

Comment: I don't know how this compiler works, but maybe you need to use the `random` outside of `nth`? Save the result into a variable and then use this variable. Your code works fine with regular SASS compilers.

Comment: Moving the `random` outside of the `nth` produces the second error.